# How can I increase the complexity of a number and maintain uniqueness

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations, cryptography, hash-function

I have an 8-digit number and you have an 8-digit number - I want to see if our numbers are the same without either of us passing the other our actual number. Hashing the numbers is the obvious solution. However, if you send me your hashed number and I do not have it - it is very easy to hash all the permutations of an 8-digit number and see your number.

I am looking for a way to increase the complexity of the 8-digit number while maintaining uniqueness and a universal process (i.e. we need to be able to apply the same process on both ends.) Squaring the number or something like that will not work because there are the same number of unique squares of an 8 digit number as there are unique 8 digit permutations. Salting will not work for the same reason.

Is there anything I can do to the number to make brute-forcing all permutations not viable?

Comment: Comment only since it's not a thought through answer. Without in some sense exchanging more information, I doubt it. If you each had public key encryption enabled you might be able to do this with some variant on digital signatures.

Comment: You probably need to use a trusted third party to compare the keys and tell you the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only $10^8$ eight digit numbers, even if you allow leading zeros.  No deterministic operation can increase the entropy of this.  Your example of squaring is a good one.  It makes the number larger, but does not increase the number of results.  You need more possible codes, either by adding digits or by having more digits as in allowing other characters.

One other approach is to make a *very* slow checking algorithm.  If it takes an hour to check a code (and that is acceptable if somebody has the code), brute forcing would require a considerable investment in computing resources.  One could still buy $10^4$ computers, set them running in parallel, and have the answer in a month and a half.

Comment: Thanks! The very slow checking algo would work for my application. Do you know anywhere I could read up more on that? I am aware of bcrypt and scrypt but as far as I know, they will not work for my application due to the random salt added.

Comment: You can just specify a huge number of trips through some hash function.  Alternately, you can use a third party who just doesn't give the answer for an hour.

Comment: If you want a slow-to-calculate function, also check out [proof of work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system) but note that you'd have to adapt -- a typical pow system is hard to calculate but easy to verify, whereas you want one that is hard to calculate and also hard to verify.  e.g. maybe you can hash the proof itself.

Answer (score 1):

In Cryptography, There are two interesting problems;

1. [Yao's Millionaires Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao%27s_Millionaires%27_Problem): In which two millionaires want to know who is the reacher without revealing their riches to the other.
2. [Socialist Millionaires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires) : In which two millionaires want to know their wealth is equal or not without revealing their riches to the other.

You can think the first one as a secure $>$ and the second one as secure $=$

Therefore, the second one can compare the values without revealing the value.

**Note 1:** these problems are part of [secure multi-party computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_multi-party_computation).

**Note 2:** You can also solve this by using SPAKE2. I've given a complete answer in [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/72740/18298)

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to use a scheme with a trusted third party. Let the two parties be A and B, and the trusted third party be X.

1. A sends X its key K1 and gets back some sort of token T1. This token needs to have some small lifetime guarantees etc.
2. B sends X it’s key K2 and gets back another token T2.
3. A and B exchange tokens. Each sends {T1, T2} to X and X responds if they are identical.

Now the token provider X should provide tokens in such a way that the same key K will generate a different token whenever the request is made etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately having an independent third party is not viable in my application.

Comment: @SphereOverload Then it may be useful to rethink why you need to compare two numbers, i.e., think about the overall design. You could perhaps have a time intensive hash and let the numbers have a small lifetime so that most brute force attacks will not be possible.